# Updating excel files functions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a function that can update (add data) to existing .xlsx files.

```
def update_excel(path, sheetname, data):
  filename = path
  with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode='a',engine="openpyxl") as writer:
     print('SHEETNAME', sheetname)
     df = pd.read_excel(path, sheetname)
     cols_del= 'Unnamed: 0'
     del df[cols_del]
     print('SHEETNAME1', sheetname)
     df = pd.concat((df, data),sort=True)
     print('SHEETNAME2', sheetname)
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)
     print('SHEETNAME3', sheetname)
     writer.save()
     print('SHEETNAME4', sheetname)
     print("Booked")
```

Current example: this takes the data of sheet1 and updates it with new entries but writes the new updated version to a new sheet named sheet11 instead of sheet1. In all the print statements above it prints sheet1 so i am very confused.

When opening the excel file as normal i get an error message from excel saying:

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename. xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?

I think this leads to excel recovering as much as they can from Sheet1 then placing it into this Sheet11 which has the updates, how can i remove this error?

Comment: `filename` is not defined in your function. You are not trying to read and write to the same file, right?

Comment: also,  if the excel file is open, it will be locked for editing, so require `try: except:` or similar type of checking.

Comment: @crayxt yes i am tying to read and write to the same file. I defined filename= path

Comment: @D.L The excel files are all closed when executing this function

Answer (score 0):

Create, write to and save a workbook:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                   index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

To specify the sheet name:

```
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx",
             sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

If you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

ExcelWriter can also be used to append to an existing Excel file:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                    mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
```

the instructions (for getting a dataframe to excel) can be found here too:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @ D.L I have updated my question above, essentially the update is occuring but instead of updating the read from sheet it updates it then writes the updated version to a new sheet

Comment: that is a good alternative that avoids the issue...

Comment: how can I update the same sheet instead of rewriting to a new sheet with the updates?

Comment: I believe that if you write to the same sheet, that it will overwrite the existing data, or are you asking how to append the data in a sheet ? (which is probably best as a new stack question question).